# Copy a file and overwrite the existing file

Tags: files, cp, file-copy

I have two images (image1.png and image2.png) in the same folder on my server, I want to run a command that overwrites image2.png to image1.png. I prefer to overwrite the image instead of deleting it and then replace it by the other one. How can I achieve that via ssh command line?

Answer (score 5):

```
ssh host "cd path/to/directory && cp image1.png image2.png"
```

The `&&` is safer than `;` in case the `cd` fails, e.g. because of a typo: in such a case, the `cp` won't be executed instead of possibly copying a wrong file.

Comment: why not a `mv` instead of a `cp`?

Comment: @1_CR The OP didn't say that he wanted to remove `image1.png`. But he can use `mv` if this gives the behavior he wants...

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I got "operation not permitted"

Comment: @MinaIsaac Then, before the `cp`, you should do a `chmod`. For instance: `... && chmod 600 image2.png && cp image1.png image2.png` (this is just an example, you can do something slightly different, e.g. with `cp` options to preserve the permissions of `image1.png`).

Comment: I tried what you said but the file always reset back to its default permissions. Is there any method I can use to force permissions change? Thank you.

Comment: @Minalsaac - you have to elevate permissions - if you can. `ssh -t ... 'cd $path && sudo cp ./file1 ./file2'` - but it might be better if you just logged on to a priveleged account initially when connecting with `ssh` in the first place.

Comment: Add 'sudo' before 'chmod'

Comment: @RuslanGerasimov - but you need to ensure you get a `-t`ty with `ssh` or you may not be able to use `sudo` at all.

Comment: @mikeserv I agree with your comment, so find please my answer and see the explanation on how to use `ssh` with `sudo`

Comment: @MinaIsaac For the permission, you can use the `-p` option of `cp` or another `chmod` after the `cp`: `cp ... && chmod your_permissions image2.png`.

Comment: The message _operation not permitted_ (as opposed to _permission denied_) usually indicates a problem with extended file attributes (`lsattr`/`chattr`) rather than basic file permissions.

Comment: `mv` would not overwrite the existing file, but replace it.

Comment: @Gilles - good point - an unlink operation vs a < stream >

Answer (score 1):

Without `sudo` the command `ssh server "cd path/to/directory && cp image1.png image2.png"` doesn't have privileges to `chmod` the permissions.

But with `sudo` it would, but being run after `ssh`, it never gets password input for it on the remote server, so the solution is use `-S` and pipe a password for `sudo` as follows:

`ssh server " cd path/to/directory && echo sudo_password | sudo -S chmod 600 image2.png && cp image1.png image2.png"`

*EDIT:*

*However, how @terdon marked, we don't need to change permissions here, but use `sudo cp`*
*,so it comes to:*

*`ssh server " cd path/to/directory && echo sudo_password | sudo -S cp image1.png image2.png"`*

*or (in case you think that your password can be read)*

*`ssh server -t " cd path/to/directory && sudo cp image1.png image2.png"`*

UPDATE: also @terdon warned and I added this, because I think it's important to stress and make an accent on such possible realization:

> I really would remove this suggestion of using -S, it is not needed
>   and very dangerous (see @mikserv's comments and my answer). It is also
>   pointless. The only "advantage" you mention, that of being able to
>   pipe is a fringe case and in most situations you could just pipe on
>   the server instead. You can also use sshpass as you suggested or set
>   up passwordless sudo. All sorts of ways that don't store a server's
>   password as plaintext. –  terdon

On the one hand this is good for the automation with no getting `sudo` password promts and, to have completely automated code/script you would add `sshpass -p password ssh...`.

However on the server where others can easily read your sudo password provided as open text during the `ssh` session that's not recommended from the security perspectives. So, to have a `sudo` with `ssh` and be safe use `ssh -t`

`ssh -t server "cd path/to/directory && sudo chmod 600 image2.png && cp image1.png image2.png"`

Nevertheless, with `-t` it's impossible to pipe `ssh "sudo command"| command` for example `ssh -t server "cd path/to/directory && sudo"|grep "text"` but it IS possible with ussage of -S and echoing password, e.g. `ssh server 'echo password | sudo -S ls -l'| grep 'a'`

Comment: yikes. you should probably have a look at one or two of those processs' `/proc/$PID/cmdline` when doing stuff like that - you will probably quit doing it. easier still - `ps -o args= -C ssh` will - as I think - print your password at you. yeah - if I run `ssh localhost 'ps -o args= -C ssh'` it prints `ssh localhost ps -o args= -C ssh`

Comment: I'm talking about your broadcasting your `sudo` password to anyone on the system with read access to `proc` - or with permissions to run `ps` for that matter. The only saving grace to the rest of `sudo`'s madness is that it doesn't require sysadmins to pass around a privileged password - they use their own. You just threw that out the window here - making your plaintext password world readable for the life of the `ssh` process. Stop that.

Comment: And no, my comment said specifically: `ssh -t ... sudo ...` - the `-t` flag specifies that `ssh` get a `pty` so it *can* run `sudo.`

Comment: @mikeserv the question didn't require any security goals, but anyway I added some explanation to my answer.

Comment: maybe. Most questions don't explicitly require that you refrain from implementing an easy means of snooping their password - but answers that do should still be downvoted.

Comment: it is not *impossible*. Neither is that a specified case here. But then again - neither were the user permissions in the first place - and that's why my comment was just a comment. The other answer addressed all aspects of the question as asked but *a future one* - I only tried to help out by suggesting the flag. I reversed my vote because you're being sensible - I'll remove the comments when you remove the `-S` altogether. maybe not so sensible...

Comment: @mikeserv thank you for your attention to some critical moments.

Comment: Normally you don't need `sudo`... unless the OP hasn't said something particular about the accounts (but in such a case, a better `ssh` configuration may be better than `sudo`).

Comment: Why are you changing the permissions of the files? That is neither requested nor necessary. All you need is `sudo cp img1 img2`.

Comment: @terdon thank you, I added this point to the answer's _edit_.

Comment: I really would remove this suggestion of using -S, it is not needed and very dangerous (see @mikserv's comments and my answer). It is also pointless. The only "advantage" you mention, that of being able to pipe is a fringe case and in most situations you could just pipe on the server instead. You can also use sshpass as you suggested or set up passwordless sudo. All sorts of ways that don't store a _server's_ password as plaintext.

Comment: @terdon please be aware that I found your comment useful and quoted your warning in the answer. You can find it in update. Thanks

Comment: @vinc17 - my sentiments exactly.

Answer (score 1):

In order to connect to a server via ssh and run a specific command, all you need is 
        ssh "command"

In your case, you want to copy a file (it overwrites by default) so you want the `cp` command. It works like `cp /path/to/original /path/to/copy`. Now, you said in your comments that trying this gives you a permission denied error. This means that you will need to run the command as root. This is done using `sudo`, so `sudo cp /path/to/original /path/to/copy`.

The next issue is that ssh runs a non-interactive shell with no tty so `sudo` can't ask for a password. You will need to use ssh's `-t` for that. So, putting all this together, you can do:

```
ssh -t user@server sudo cp /path/to/image2.png /path/to/image1.png
```

Do **not** ever echo your `sudo` password as suggested by another answer. That is extremely dangerous since it will make it visible to any users connected on the system and it will also be kept in your history file in plain text. This means that all I need to do is `grep sudo ~youruser/.bash_history` and I have your password and complete access to the server. So any attacker who gains access to the server can now do anything they like.

Comment: Wow - I *really* didn't think of that - that makes it all the more scary. At first I was thinking the history thing might depend on the `sudoers` config and the value of `$HOME` - but even that matters not at all. Of course regardless of how that is setup you still do the `echo` before ever `sudo` is invoked at all. Yikes.